# Create a file system corruption on a embedded device

Tags: testing, filesystems, embedded

I'm working on a project where we are using a file system (NAND Flash) on our device.

We noteiced that sometimes, when we have a power shut down or we are resseting the software (by debugger).

The file system is corrupted after restart.

Now we try to do several improvements, like adding journaling or garbage collection.

But my main question is now, how could I create a filesystem corruption by my own, to test if the new mechanism is working.

Currently it is very hard to reproduce the failure state and I want to find a clear way to reproduce the failure state.

Has anyone some hints?

Comment: These things almost certainly happen when there is a reset or power outage during flash write. The way to dodge such problems in safety-critical systems is to store everything in double "mirror" segments, with CRC at the end. And have the program check that both segments are valid upon start-up. It will be possible to recover as long as one of the segments is intact. It's slow and tedious however.

Answer (score 2):

Techniques such as journaling protect against unplanned shutdown that would cause incomplete operations to leave data structures in an invalid state.  That is not quite the same as "corruption" more broadly.

A spontaneous modification of some random location asynchronous to and independent of file-system operations are unlikely to be detected or healed by journaling.  It is arguably an unlikely failure mode, and not the failure mode you are experiencing when you have a power loss.

NAND flash itself is inherently unreliable and NAND controllers have built-in error detection and correction means.

The point is that the techniques you have applied *prevent* the filesystem from becoming invalid rather then healing corruption, so simply corrupting the filesystem will not prove the effectiveness of your solution; it will merely corrupt the file system.

The "failure state" addresses by journaling is to have an incomplete operaton - a file opened for write to which data has been written but not closed at the point power-loss or reset.

Rather then try to invoke some kind of corruption, you might do better to replicate the conditions under which failure previously occurred, by having test code that continuously creates and writes files and verifies they are valid while asynchronously and randomly cycling the power (ideally through a relay or "smart" power-supply that can be controlled by a PC or the EUT itself for example), or simply random timer interrupt that issues a reset asynchronous to the file operations.

You need to understand how your journaling system works.  At its simplest it will simply leave the file in the state it was *before* it was opened - so it does not prevent data loss, merely filesystem data structure errors rendering files or the whole filesystem unusable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer the question you *want* answered, not the question you asked.

As @Clifford said, what you need in order to test your new mechanism is not to introduce corruption, but rather to introduce a condition similar to a power failure.

How to achieve that depends on how you do your testing and development.

If your filesystem interacts directly with the NAND firmware, and you can't run it against a simulator, you have to go all the way and have your test suit actually automate power outages from software (there are software-controlled switches to do that).

If your filesystem can run on any block device, then you can do the following:

1. Create a btrfs filesystem on your test machine.
2. Create a large file on the btrfs filesystem.
3. mkfs your filesystem on the large file and mount it.
4. Issue a lot of operations against the mounted filesystem.
5. While the operations are running, take a btrfs snapshot.
6. Unmount your filesystem.
7. Unmount brtfs and mount the snapshot.
8. Remount your filesystem onto the snapshot of the loopback file.
9. Test that the filesystem is consistent.

Obviously, it doesn't have to be brtfs, any filesystem with snapshot support will do.